# Using names() and make.names() inside a loop

Tags: r, variable-names

I am reading some files into R with a "for loop" and naming them based on the looping index.  I have used the `assign` fucntion to dynamically name one data frame for each file being read as follows:

```
for (i in 1:10){
    assign(paste0("df",i),read_csv(paste0("file",i,".csv")))
}
```

This works fine. However, while inside the for loop, I also want to do some other operations to the data frame, but I dont know how to refer to it given that the name is changing as the loop progresses.
I want to add to the loop something along the lines of:

```
names(paste0("df",i)) <- make.names(names(paste0("df",i)))
```

I want to execute the above command but I don't know how to properly pass the changing data frame name to the names() function.

Thanks in advance,

MR

Comment: Try `eval(parse(text = paste0("df", i, " <- make.names(names(df", i, "))")))`

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks Milan

Comment: No worries Mario! Glad it helped.